# Headphones not working in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, headphones

I've tried multiple ways to solve my problem as described in other topics in this forum, but none succeeded. The Headphones sound worked when I first installed Ubuntu 12.10, but after a few updates it ceased to function. Sound works fine with the speakers but as soon as I insert the jack, there is nothing but silence. I've checked Alsamixer and when I insert the jack it mutes the speakers but not the Headphones column.
I've even tried installing the drivers from Realtek but it was a very bad idea since it crashed my OS completely and I had to re-install everything. I'm a bit on the newbie in this Ubuntu thing in case you haven't noticed ;)
Anyway I would really appreciate some help here since I have a small baby and she sleeps a lot so I can't disturb her with the sound coming from the speakers.
I have a Toshiba Satellite P200-1IE and Ubuntu 12.10.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the contents of `/var/lib/alsa/asound.state`

Comment: Ok, here it is: http://ubuntuone.com/3EwMdk6AdMcfwOFBieo2yo

Comment: Try setting the `Front Headphone Jack` to `true` with alsamixer.

Comment: Ok, I edited the above mentioned file, and set the value beneath Front Headphone Jack to true... but without sucess... still no sound from the headphones...

Answer (score 3):

1. Open a terminal.
2. Run `alsamixer` (type the command and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
3. Press <kbd>F6</kbd> then just disable the automute button.

Please make sure that you have your headphone jack inserted while doing all this.

Comment: Disabling auto-mute turns on the sound on the normal speakers not on the headphones.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (same computer / same problem). I resolved it by installing the lastest drivers from alsa-project:

```
wget ftp://ftp.alsa-project.org/pub/driver/alsa-driver-1.0.25.tar.bz2
tar -jxf alsa-driver-1.0.25.tar.bz2
cd alsa-driver-1.0.25/
./configure --with-cards=hda-intel --with-oss=yes
make
sudo make install
```

restart your computer and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

In this file: /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf

Comment those line as shown: 

`[Jack Front Headphone]`

`#required-any = any`

`[Jack Headphone]`

`#required-any = any`

Restart PulseAudio without root:
`pulseaudio -k`

After that Headphones should appear in the System settings > Sound, but they will be disabled. Click on them and then button to enable them. 
WARNING: only the audio output that is selected will produce sound!

Comment: It didn't work for me. i m using toshiba sattelite.Do I need to restart system after this change?

Comment: Doesn't work, even screws up normal speaker output: sound doesn't return after headphones removed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this fixed it for me:

1. Download the basic run.py script to your preferred download folder by following the instructions on http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/HDA_Analyzer i.e. run the following command in a terminal `wget -O run.py http://www.alsa-project.org/hda-analyzer.py`
2. Check that the permissions of run.py are set to root by using `sudo chown root:root /<download location>/run.py`
3. In a terminal change run.py to an executable file using `sudo chmod +x /<download location>/run.py`
4. Run the script in a terminal `sudo python run.py`
5. In the left-hand sidebar select Node[0x15] PIN
6. Check the box next to EAPD
7. Click Exp then save as 'snd_hda_codec_diff.py' in /etc
8. Add "python /etc/snd_hda_codec_diff.py" without the quotes to the file /etc/rc.local just above the line "exit 0" with your favourite editor

After the next reboot your headphones should work.
Hope this helps.